# I need help using mutable reference in different functions

Tags: rust

I am learning rust so some things might seem obvious and easy but I can't understand some things.

I need to have `income` and `expenses` variables to change their value, usually I would use a `static` variable and assign value in an `unsafe` block.

Here is the code:

```rust
fn expense_sum(expense_list: &Vec<u64>, expenses: &mut u64) {
    expenses = &mut (expense_list.iter().sum());
}

fn prompt_expense(expense_list: &mut Vec<u64>, expense_name: &mut Vec<String>, expenses: &mut u64) {
    let expense_input: u64 = 1;
    expense_list.push(expense_input);

    let expense_name1: String = "test1".to_string();

    expense_name.push(expense_name1);

    expense_sum(&expense_list, expenses);
    println!("Total user expenses: {}", expenses);
}

fn main() {
    let mut expense_list: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    let mut expense_name: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut expenses: u64;

    loop {
        prompt_expense(&mut expense_list, &mut expense_name, &mut expenses);
        // USe income and expenses here for analysis
    }
}
```

I've tested in many ways, but I could not get to pass succesfully the variables to `expense_sum` and `income_sum`

Comment: *"usually I would use a static variable and assign value in an unsafe block."* You shouldn't usually use unsafe

Comment: Should have added that I'm doing rust for 2 days, so it's not been a long time using it :D

Comment: That's fine. Just listen to the compiler, he will tell you what's wrong. E.g. using of uninitialized variables, redundant parentheses, not assigned variables etc.

Comment: And don't use a static variable. The simplest solution is to pass around what you need in a variable.

Comment: Make sure to use `rustfmt` next time. In fact you should use it all the time, when you write code, because it will format your code properly and you won't loose track on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly correct; they only real issue preventing it from building is here:

```
fn expense_sum(expense_list: &Vec<u64>, expenses: &mut u64) {
    expenses = &mut (expense_list.iter().sum());
}
```

This syntax tries to assign the reference, instead of modifying the actual value referred. You need to dereference and then simply assign:

```
*expenses = expense_list.iter().sum();
```

That being said, this is bad practice. It's much better to simply return the value using... the return value of the function:

```
fn expense_sum(expense_list: &Vec<u64>) -> u64 {
    expense_list.iter().sum()
}
```

That way the code is shorter and much readable, and you avoid all the unnecessary reference handling. You'll need to modify your `prompt_expense` function in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will follow your suggestions and return the value from the function instead of messing with references.